# Customising Code Contract Exception Messages

Tags: c#, exception, code-contracts

I have a code contract expresses as this - it validates that entity to be stored is not null and is valid for persistence. It works. Fab.

```
[ContractClassFor(typeof(IRepository<,>))]
internal abstract class ContractsForIRepository<T, TId> : IRepository<T, TId> where T : IEntity
{
    private ContractsForIRepository()
    {

    } 

    public T Persist(T entity)
    {
        Contract.Requires<InvalidEntityException>(entity != null, "Entity is null");
        Contract.Requires<InvalidEntityException>(entity.IsValidForPersistence(), "Entity not valid for persistence");
        return default(T);
    }

}
```

However, I would like the exception to be more useful - as anyone receiving the message will want to know what entity was invalid and what is looked like. All of the entities override ToString(), so I wanted to include this in the error message:

```
Contract.Requires<InvalidEntityException>(entity.IsValidForPersistence(), "Entity not valid for persistence " + entity.ToString());
```

I have included ToString to be explicit - it would be called implicitly if I omitted it, but I think it makes my question clearer.

The problem is, this isn't allowed by code contracts and I get the following message.

> User message to contract call can only be string literal, or a static field, or static property that is at least internally visible.

Is there any way to include specific data in the exception message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According the [documentation](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/userdoc.pdf):

> **2.10 Overloads on Contract Methods**
>
> All of the contract methods have overloads that take a string in
>   addition to the boolean condition:
>
> `Contract.Requires(x != null, "If x is null, then the missiles are red!");`
>
> The user-supplied string will be displayed whenever the contract is
>   violated at runtime. **Currently, it must be a compile-time constant**.

So, what you are asking is not possible.

Comment: So this message `User message to contract call can only be string literal, or a static field, or static property that is at least internally visible.` appears to be a blatant lie... :S